# Angular rzslider: max value for min & min value for max; range slider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, slider

I'm making a range slider using [rzslider](https://github.com/angular-slider/angularjs-slider), with behaviour as follows:

- floor = -10, ceiling = 10
- minRange = 1
- starting values, minValue = -5; maxValue = 5
- noSwitching = true

And what I'm having trouble with:

- the minValue needs a ceiling of 0, and the maxValue needs a floor of 0, so the range can never be e.g. 1-5.

---

*Edit:*

Possible values could be: -2,5 or -4,1

Values not allowed include: 2,4 or -9,-2

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the Range slider example in [https://jsfiddle.net/dyf8maqb/8.

```
$scope.minRangeSlider = {
    minValue: -5,
    maxValue: 5,  
    options: {
        floor: -10,
        ceil: 10,
        step: 1,
        noSwitching: true,
        minRange: 1,
        onEnd: function () {
            $scope.minRangeSlider.minValue = Math.min($scope.minRangeSlider.minValue,0);
            $scope.minRangeSlider.maxValue = Math.max($scope.minRangeSlider.maxValue,0);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply - but nope, that's pretty much what I've got at the moment. I need the lower end of the range not to be able to be higher than 0, and the upper end of the range not to be able to be lower than 0.

So some possible values would be -5,2 | 0,3 | -1,9

But 2,5 or -9,-1 would not be allowed.

Is that any clearer?

Comment: I thought you might be able to simply add the onChange event

Comment: That doesn't work reliably, you're right, but it's a step in the right direction! I'll keep playing around with it and update if I get anywhere.

Comment: This is the cleanest I can make it.  Unfortunately it didn't stop the drag at 0, but will ping back to 0 if they go over the limit when they release - using onEnd, rather than onChange.

Comment: Hm, I'll maybe look into hiding the labels when the lower cursor is dragged above 0 or the higher cursor above 0; other than that I'll jump into the source and see what can be done there. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think I should be able to add something in round about here in the same vein as the applyMinMaxLimit function: https://github.com/angular-slider/angularjs-slider/blob/master/src/rzslider.js#L1998

Comment: @KScandrett Could you see this link please. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45350964/make-32-hrs-range-in-rzslider-in-angular-js

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it (see https://jsfiddle.net/dyf8maqb/11/)

```
<div style="width:50%;float:left">
    <rzslider rz-slider-model="minRangeSlider.value" rz-slider-options="minRangeSlider.options"></rzslider>
</div>
<div style="width:50%;float:left">
    <rzslider rz-slider-model="maxRangeSlider.value" rz-slider-options="maxRangeSlider.options"></rzslider>
</div>

$scope.minRangeSlider = {
    value: -5,
    options: {
        floor: -10,
        ceil: 0,
        step: 1,
        translate: function(value, id, label) {
          return (label === 'ceil') ? '' : value;
        }
    }
};

$scope.maxRangeSlider = {
    value: 5,
    options: {
        floor: 0,
        ceil: 10,
        step: 1,
        translate: function(value, id, label) {
          return (label === 'floor') ? '' : value;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: This is really two sliders side by side. The translate function hides the two '0's in the middle