# Make 32 Hrs range in RZSlider in Angular Js?

Tags: javascript, angular, date

I have to implement one RZSlider with 10 minutes interval with 32Hrs. I am using date picker also. So I set this date picker and time slider into one html page. If when I land on this page then It should be select by default today date with 8 Hrs window, Mean -4Hrs and +4Hrs with current date. For Example: If I land on this page 23 july at 23:00, Then range should be 19:00 to 3:00. But In this case 3:00 comes into 24 July. I want to make this slider like date picker with time.

> starting from 8:10,8:20,8:30,8:40,8:50,9:10.....12:10,12:20.......23:10,23:20,23:30,23:40,23:50,00:00,00.10,00:20,00:30,00:40,00:50,1:00.......4:00 End To.

I already implement some logic for 32Hrs range but this is failing in some cases then slider will break and compatible issue will comes.
I am not able show my code because code is dependent on other code.

```js
var app = angular.module('rzSliderDemo', ['rzModule', 'ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $timeout) {
  var arr = getRange().map(n => {
    return {
      value: n,
      legend: n
    };
  });
  
  $scope.slider = {
    minValue: '10.50',
    maxValue: '14.20',
    options: {
      showTicks: true,
      stepsArray: arr,
      draggableRange: true,
    }
  };
});

function getRange() {
  var arr = [];
  var d = new Date(2017, 1, 1);
  for (var i = 0; i < (6 * 28); i++) {
    d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + 10);
    arr.push(leadZero(d.getHours()) + '.' + leadZero(d.getMinutes()));
  }
  return arr;
}

function leadZero(time) {
  return time < 10 ? '0' + time : time;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/rzajac/angularjs-slider/master/dist/rzslider.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.14.3/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/rzajac/angularjs-slider/master/dist/rzslider.js"></script>
<div ng-app="rzSliderDemo">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="wrapper">
    <header>
      <h1>AngularJS Touch Slider</h1>

    </header>
    <article>
      <h2>Simple slider</h2>
      Model:
      <input type="text" ng-model="slider.minValue" />
      <input type="text" ng-model="slider.maxValue" />
      <br/>
      <rzslider rz-slider-model="slider.minValue" rz-slider-high="slider.maxValue" rz-slider-options="slider.options"></rzslider>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this example It is going to next day 4 hrs but not going to previous date Hrs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not completely clear on what you're after but hopefully this will set you on the right track.

I'm using [Moment](http://momentjs.com/) to make working with dates easier.

By including the day in the range value it makes the value unique so we can set the initial start and end times without ambiguity.

You can then use Moment to transform selected values back into date objects when you're ready to do something with the values.

```js
var app = angular.module('rzSliderDemo', ['rzModule', 'ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $timeout) {
  
  var startDate, endDate, startTime, endTime;
  var currentDate = moment();
  
  var timeData = getRange();
  $scope.localTime = timeData.currentTime; // actually start of this hour
  
  var arr = timeData.times.map(n => {
    return {
      value: n.value
      //legend: n.value
    };
  });
  
  $scope.slider = {
    minValue: $scope.localTime.clone().subtract(4, "hours").format('MMM Do hh:mma'),
    maxValue: $scope.localTime.clone().add(4, "hours").format('MMM Do hh:mma'),
    options: {
      showTicks: true,
      stepsArray: arr,
      draggableRange: true,
    }
  };
});

function getRange(currentDate) {
  var arr = [];
  var totalHourRange = 28;
  var currentTime = moment(); // current date and time using Moment
  
  // set current time to beginning of the hour
  currentTime.minute(0);
  
  // clone date and substract 1/2 total range to get start point
  var tmpTime = currentTime.clone();
  tmpTime.subtract(totalHourRange / 2, 'hours');
  
  // offset is the number of minutes from the current point
  for (var i = -((6 * totalHourRange) / 2); i <= (6 * totalHourRange) / 2; i++) {
    arr.push({value: tmpTime.format('MMM Do hh:mma'), offset: i * 10});
    tmpTime.add(10, 'minutes');
  }
  return { times: arr, currentTime: currentTime, totalHourRange: totalHourRange };
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/rzajac/angularjs-slider/master/dist/rzslider.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.14.3/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/rzajac/angularjs-slider/master/dist/rzslider.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="rzSliderDemo">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="wrapper">
    <header>
      <h2>AngularJS Touch Slider</h2>
    </header>
    <article>
      <h4>Local time (beginning of the hour): <em>{{localTime.format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a')}}</em></h4>
      <br />
      Model:
      <input type="text" ng-model="slider.minValue" />
      <input type="text" ng-model="slider.maxValue" />
      <br />
      <br />
      <rzslider rz-slider-model="slider.minValue" rz-slider-high="slider.maxValue" rz-slider-options="slider.options"></rzslider>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/stxa9hrp/1/**

Comment: @K Scandrett . Why you defined function getRange(currentDate) outside of controller.. Thanks for the answer

Comment: @K Scandrett. It is working. But could we set 32 hrs window. starting from Jul 28th 08:00pm to Jul 30th 04:00am

Comment: Of course. Set `totalHourRange = 32` and/or set a different start time

Comment: I putted var totalHourRange = 32; then start form 07:00pm to 03:00am

Comment: `tmpTime.subtract((totalHourRange / 2) - 1, 'hours');`

Comment: Note that my demo puts the current time in the very middle of the 32hrs, i.e. 16 hrs either side. If you want to have a fixed minimum time, such as yesterday at 8pm, then use something like `tmpTime.hour(0).subtract(4, 'hours');` instead, with `totalHourRange = 32` for a max time of tomorrow at 4am

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/stxa9hrp/1/